# Запятая перед «и» в сложном предложении

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, сложное-предложение, и

*Дует ветер, поют соловьи, качаются деревья(,) **и** льётся водичка — здесь царствует природа.*

Нужна ли запятая? Никак не могу определиться...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ответ исправлен и дополнен

*Дует ветер, поют соловьи, качаются деревья и льётся водичка — **здесь царствует природа.***

1. В данном случае к простым предложениям с бессоюзной связью присоединяется предложение с **замыкающим одиночным союзом И**.

В то же время вся группа в конце фразы имеет **общее** **поясняющее предложение** (бессоюзная связь обозначена тире).

2. Соответственно, здесь действует общее правило **для одиночного союза И**, поэтому запятая не ставится. Но при отсутствии **общего элемента** запятая перед замыкающим союзом И ставилась бы.
3. Пример **с замыкающим союзом И** и общим обстоятельством:

***К полудню** черные облака почти коснутся земли, задует сырой ветер и польются томительные, нагоняющие сон обложные дожди* (Пауст.);

http://orthographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=133#pp133, Знаки препинания в сложносочиненном предложении, § 112.

Comment: Ага, интересно-интересно! В правилах (http://orthographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=133#pp133) общая часть сложного предложения обычно находится в начале: *Останавливаться было нельзя: ноги засасывало и следы наливались водой* (Пауст.). А тут получается, что всё извернулось: *Ноги засасывало и следы наливались водой — останавливаться было нельзя*. Я правильно понимаю? P. S. Только мне кажется, что Ваше предложение из ответа [В то же время вся группа предложений имеет общую связь, обозначенную тире (общий элемент)] нужно подправить:  возникает ощущение, что *тире* является общим элементом.

Comment: Спасибо я исправила предложение. Общий элемент в виде предложения  с бессоюзной связью и тире в конце фразы меня не очень затруднил, но проблема была в самом ЗАМЫКАЮЩЕМ союзе И.  В ПАС такой союз используется в СПП с однородными придаточными, и Лопатин выделяет эту тему отдельной статьей. Хорошо, что здесь я нашла хотя бы пример с таким замыкающим союзом в ССП (в качестве возможного доказательства).